# How do I say 'I will see you' if I want to teach you a lesson or take revenge?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

If we *[see somebody](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/see_1)*, we are either visiting them or meeting them (generally for all good reasons).

A doctor advising his patient to *see him* after a week of taking medicines. A secretary telling her client to *see him* on Tuesday for the deal... and so on.

But, here is my context.

Harry did too bad to me by making fun out of me. Unfortunately, in front of everyone, I could not do anything but warn him for the consequences --*"I'll see you*" and then I left the place.

Here, I will *see Harry* but this *seeing* is different! How should I use *see somebody* that **does not mean** meeting/visiting for all good intention? Taking revenge or teaching Harry a lesson **does not require** me meeting him personally! So, here, actually, I don't see him.

When a hero says to a villain that he'll *see* him, does it merely mean *meeting* as in the general context? I don't think so. The hero uses *see* metaphorically and does not meet the villain. He may simply damage villain's properties making him riches to rags! And the hero goes off! Where did he see him? :)

In *Hindi* and my mother tongue *Gujarati*, *see you* literally means *I'll screw you when the time will come.*

Comment: "Don't act too smart, buddy. I'm leaving your for now. But don't worry, I'll see you." sounds odd to me.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Okay, simplified.

Comment: _What goes around comes around_ might have a similar meaning.

Comment: @jinawee Not at all. I'm not leaving anything to the destiny. It's **me** who'll teach him a lesson and not anyone else. What goes around .... idiom talks about the rule of the nature that does not require someone's efforts as here in this case.

Comment: @MaulikV I think it's odd to think of someone saying, "I'll see you," and leaving the party, spitefully. I think a better phrase might be "You'll see me again."

Comment: @DamkerngT. The question still stands! You'll see me again, but it's not a normal meeting or visit. The question is using *seeing* in that context and not who sees whom.

Comment: @MaulikV I think this *see* is even closer to the basic sense of "see" than the one used in *seeing a doctor*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. The question is when you *see somebody* (as all dictionaries describe) it does not mean the way I used it. That's what the question is all about. *seeing somebody* is visiting/meeting but never in the context of teaching a lesson.

Comment: To me, "You'll see me again" means "You just wait. And I will appear in front of you (and thus be visible to you) once again."

Comment: I see nobody has mentioned the (spoken with an aggressive Scottish accent) possibility of *I'll "**See you, Jimmy!**"* ("verbifying" the stereotypical drunken Glaswegian's phrase used to invite you to have a fight, so he can teach you a lesson).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This use of *see* is not idiomatic in Anglo-American English. The corresponding minatory phrase is

> *I'll **get** you!*

This probably represents an underlying “I’ll get you back” = “I will repay you for this injury”.

That idiom suggests a line that Arnold Schwarzenegger's *Terminator* films have made into a paradigmatic threat:

> *I'll be back.*

It may also be possible that “I’ll get you” represents “I’ll get you where I want you” = “I will cause you to occupy an unpleasant situation in which I would like to see you”. I suggest this because there is an old AAE idiom, little used today but once popular in melodramatic dialogue, which used *see* in this sense.

> *I'll see you damned / in hell / hanged / in jail!*

This does not imply literal presence when the addressee is in the named predicament, but gleeful anticipation of that situation. There is a discussion of one common (and still current) variant at [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/77327/24489).

Comment: +1 Thanks for saving me a question. In Iron Man 2008, Rodey says to Toney, 'When I get up in the morning and I'm putting on my uniform, you know what I recognize? I see in that mirror that every person that's got this uniform will get my back!' @Maulik V

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng *I've got **your** back* is quite different from *I will get **you** back*. *Got your back* means *I have got your back **covered***: I am protecting your back while you are engaged with opponents in front of you.

Comment: I forgot to mention 'get my back' = 'protect me'. Yes, StoneyB is right:) @Maulik V I sometimes confuse these two. http://www.idiomquest.com/learn/idiom/I-got-your-back/ is a good source. :)

Comment: Isn't this usage possible? The scene is I'm pointing my finger at you and uttering in anger ... *"I'll see you later."* It certainly means I'll come back and take revenge. I think it's an obvious expression to be understood with *see* used in a special way.

Comment: @MaulikV It's certainly possible, and intelligible. But it is not an AAE idiom or stock phrase. I would not, as a playwright, put it into the mouth of an American character, as I might *I'll get you* or (if I wanted to get a laugh) *I'll be back*.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most idiomatic phrase that uses "see" would be

> You haven't seen the last of me

Which means, basically, "This incident may be complete, but I will arrange for there to be another incident, which I intend to be in control of."

It's possible for this be used in a relatively unthreatening manner (such as after you have suffered a loss in some sporting event, to indicate your desire for a rematch), but most often it indicates a desire to administer a beating or humiliation at least as severe as what you have just received.

Comment: This is infinitely better than the accepted answer.